# Feedback about using make on a project with many subdirectories

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, makefile

To my Object Oriented Programming course, I must do a final proyect (academic purposes). I want to make a proyect "the right way" (ie: makefile, modular, DRY, easily scalable, etc) in order to better understand classes, makefile and C++.

The idea I've got is to have a "tree-source-file-structure-directory" so in each subfolder i'd got the source files with it's headers, test files and single makefile.
So if I want to work on the interface, I go to the subfolder interface, I edit the files, I run the tests, if everything is OK, simply I link the objects together on my root directory. Same thing if I want to work on my data structure, and so goes on. The nice feature is that in every subfolder resides along the source code and the object files, so the linker in my root directory would search for object files already compiled on subfolders and link them together

I've been searching on the internet, and I could see many different solutions:
-Doing make recursively, eg:

```
SUBDIRS=eda
.PHONY: subdirs $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

The problem I found is that my prerequisites on "eda" folder would be "quirky"

-Using **Automatic Variable** $(@D), but I didn't quite understand how it works
-Maybe using wildcard function, but I am a little confused about this option.

**Anyways**, the most tempting solution for me was the first one (using make recursively), but I found lot of comments saying that it is not recommended to use *make* recursively [Interesting article](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/)

So I want to ask you guys some advices: How can I accomplish my objectives and have every important module in a separate folder? is recursive make the best solution? Maybe I should dive in "automake"? Or perhaps it would be better to take all the object files to a new "object" subfolder on root directory and then link them together?

By the way, I took the inspiration to make my proyect with this tree structure by sniffing Amarok source code: it has a subfolder called "src", and when you enter there, you can see a lot of subfolders: equalizer, playlist, dynamic, statusbar, core, playlistgenerator, playlistmanager, etc. And many subfolders have their own subdirectories... and the result is an incredible music player. If this method works fine to the Amarok team... I could be able to do something similar!

Any comments, feedback, suggestions and others are welcome, thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT #1**

**Beta**, I have some implicit rules (suffix) and a target for the linker that needs a object on my *eda* folder. Every other prerequisite of this target is built on the current folder.
The problem I have, is that when I run make to build that target, it takes the **name of my prerequisite on "eda" folder** as a target to build with the implicit rule. That's the tricky/unclean part of the makefile recursive on my proyect: I guess I must create a special implicit rule for every object file that make must search in a subfolder.

That's why I want some feedback: ¿Are there better alternatives? Or the advantages of using make recursive in my proyects overwhelm the other alternatives?

Anyways, if gives you better understanding, here is my *draft Makefile* (it is in spnish-english :P )

```
#Makefile hecho para las pruebas de los archivos dentro de esta carpeta
FLAGS=-g -DDEBUG

OUT_TI=TIndividuo

OUT_TP=TProfesor
OUT_TA=TAula

.SUFFIXES: .cpp .c .h .o
.c.o: ; cc $(FLAGS) -c $*.c
.cc.o: ; gcc $(FLAGS) -c $*.cc
.cpp.o: ; g++ $(FLAGS) -c $*.cpp

SUBDIRS=eda
.PHONY: subdirs $(SUBDIRS) 

$(OUT_TI): eda/TAula.o CandidatoHorario.o TIndividuo.o TIndividuoTest.o TGen.o
    g++ CandidatoHorario.o TIndividuo.o TIndividuoTest.o TGen.o eda/TAula.o -o $@
CandidatoHorario.o: CandidatoHorario.cpp CandidatoHorario.h
TIndividuoTest.o: TIndividuoTest.cpp TIndividuo.h
TIndividuo.o: TIndividuo.cpp TIndividuo.h
TGen.o: TGen.cpp
#eda/TAula.o: eda/TAula.cpp eda/TAula.h
#   g++ -c eda/TAula.cpp -o $@

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(OUT_TI) $(OUT_TA) eda/TAula.o
```

Comment: Could you explain more about the prerequisites of `eda`?

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my main post!

Comment: Just my two cents: With the "non recursive make" paper you already got the right approach, at least in my opinion... You probably know already that Android used (and still uses ?) this approach. I would follow the details given in http://evbergen.home.xs4all.nl/nonrecursive-make.html because this is rather concrete. Additionally I think you need some "targets" to generate + run your tests per subdirectory, but I do not think that this is complicated...

Comment: Ok Ingo, so you are telling me that your approach would be using "non recursive make" in order to put every object file in a "object" folder and then link them whenever they are necesary, right? I'm going to search a coffee to read your document, thanks! By the way, On my post I wrote the makefile of my "test folder": they are few "run targets" on purpose, because in this "test folder" I'm using the minimum *source-stable-files-already-tested* to test the material I found on internet abour Makefiles and subfolders.

Comment: You may be interested to look into cmake instead. cmake will generate the makefiles for you, much less effort in the end, I think. Only "problem" you have a bit of a learning curve at the start, but the power coming with cmake: you'll be able to generate makefiles on any platform that supports cmake, which is many.

Comment: _scons_ is also a nice build system. The clarity of per-directory scripts (if you want) without the drawbacks of recursive make.

Comment: Alexis, I already thought about using **cmake**, but then I **thought** that perhaps it would be better to use it on proyects that is more important building in **any platform** instead **scalability* (ie, being able to build laaaaaaarge proyects and easily *upgradeable*), this last one is the feature I want to focus on this proyect... but maybe I'm wrong and cmake is good at this both features and much more! What do you think about? Do you know a good *getting-started* guide (I forgot to tell you that it is my first *big proyect*).

Comment: edA-qa, I'd like to use a tool that is widely spread on software, I mean: Almost every open source code I download uses make, cmake or a configure script to build the proyect. That's why cmake and make are *calling me*. Guys, I'd be glad if this topic generates a healthy debate/discussion over building tools (or if anyone has a link to a discussion that has already started!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Recursive Make Considered Harmful" is certainly a paper to read and to understand. Afterwards, your selection of tools should really be tailored to your specific projects.

For small projects that you initiate (or where you have the influence to guide high-level decisions), I would recommend spending a bit of time identifying your preferences (project layout, directory structure, unit test framework, etc.) and writing a generic set of makefiles that you will use for all your projects. You could easily end up with a generic master makefile, possibly a few more generic included makefiles for modularity (e.g. to build libraries, or unit tests or automatic dependency detection). You could also provide some extra flexibility with optional included configuration makefiles (e.g. specifying the order of your libraries). Most of the DAG construction would rely heavily on the content of your project directories. An example could look like:

```
include config.mk

sources := $(wildcard *.cpp)
programs := $(sources:%.cpp=%)
lib_sources := $(wildcard lib/*/*.cpp)
lib_dirs := $(sort $(patsubst %/, %, $(dir $(lib_sources:lib/%=%))))
lib_objects := $(lib_sources:lib/%.cpp=$(BUILD)/%.o)

all: $(programs:%=$(BUILD)/%)

.PRECIOUS: %/.sentinel %.d

# for dependencies on directories in build tree
%/.sentinel:
        @mkdir -p $* && touch $@

clean:
        $(RM) -r $(BUILD)

programs_aux:=$(programs)
include $(foreach program, $(programs), program.mk)

lib_dirs_aux:=$(lib_dirs)
include $(foreach lib_dir, $(lib_dirs), lib.mk)

# this should probably be in lib.mk
-include $(lib_objects:%.o=%.d)
```

The included `program.mk` (and `lib.mk`) would contain some boilerplate code to iterate over the lists of programs (and lists of libraries) and would factor out the specific parts of the makefile to build programs (and libraries).

To help with the implementation of such makefiles, you could use some standard library like http://gmsl.sourceforge.net.

This approach has several issues:
* it leads to makefiles that require strong skills
* it doesn't always scale very well to very large projects
* it relies heavily on "convention instead of configuration" and requires a clear upfront definition of the conventions that you will use (IMO this is good others might think that it lacks flexibility)
* life is too short to mess around with makefiles

Otherwise, I would suggest using higher-level configuration tools such as SCons or CMake as they tend to be conceptually simpler and they also allow other flavours of generators.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, finally I choose to learn CMake. My motivation was the last point you wrote: *life is too short to mess around with makefiles* I think makefiles are usefull tool, but also very complex and with lots of tricks (just take a look at makefile's manual); one would take months, maybe years to completely master makefiles and still you'd remain with problems on recursive makefiles. By the other hand, CMake is very easy, simple, scalable and lacks this problem. My conclusion: makefiles for very simple and little projects, cmake for the rest